# In mongodb, how to select just the objects in a document that match the find() criteria?

Tags: mongodb

I have an "books" collection structured like this:

```
 {
    "isbn" : 101,
    "title" : "One",
    "author" : "Mike",
    "year" : 1980,
    "awards" : [
        {"award" : "Nebula", "year" : 1987},
        {"award" : "Hugo", "year" : 1985},
    ],
    "reviews" : [
        {"user_id" : 1, "rating" : 10, "text" : "Awesome book"},
        {"user_id" : 2, "rating" : 4, "text" : "Terrible book"},
        {"user_id" : 5, "rating" : 7, "text" : "Good book"},
    ]
}
```

I want to select just the review objects (not the whole document) that, for an example, have a rating higher than 5, so that my results be like this:

```
"reviews" : [ 
        {"user_id" : 1, "rating" : 10, "text" : "Awesome book"},
        {"user_id" : 5, "rating" : 7, "text" : "Good book"},
]
```

How do I write the db.books.find() query to do that?

Comment: You will need to use unwind in the aggregation framework for this

Comment: @SalvadorDali Oops, that's right. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically as it was mentioned by Sammaye, you need to use aggregation framework. Currently I do not have mongo on my machine, so I can not verify that my query will work, but I assume that something like this have to do the job:

```
db.books.aggregate(
  { $unwind : "$reviews" },
  { $match : {
     "reviews.rating": {$gt : 5}
  }})
```

Just to make it more complete, you can use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/), but it will return only the first result (which is not what you need, but may be someone else will need)